# oracle sqlldr not recognizing special characters

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am facing a scenario where the sqlldr is not being able to recognize special characters. I usually don't bother about this as its not important for me to have the exact same names however this led to another issue which is causing the system to malfunction.

**unittesting.txt**

```
8888888,John SMITÉ,12345678
```

**unittesting.ctl**

```
load data
CHARACTERSET UTF8
infile 'PATH/unittesting.txt'
 INSERT
 into table temp_table_name
 Fields Terminated By ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS(
 ID_NO                 CHAR(50) "TRIM(:ID_NO)" ,
 NAME                  CHAR(50) "TRIM(:NAME)" ,
 ID_NO2                CHAR(50) "TRIM(:ID_NO2)" )
```

**SQLLDR command**

```
sqlldr DB_ID/DB_PASS@TNS 
control=PATH/unittesting.ctl 
log=PATH/unittesting.log 
bad=PATH/unittesting.bad 
errors=100000000
```

**OUTPUT from table**

```
|ID_NO      |NAME                    |ID_NO2 |
|8888888    |John SMIT�12345678     |        |
```

**Other information about system [RHEL 7.2, Oracle 11G]**

```
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

select userenv('language') from dual
OUTPUT: AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

file -i unittesting.txt
OUTPUT: unittesting.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1

echo $LANG
OUTPUT: en_US.UTF-8
```

**Edit:**

So i tried to change the encoding as advised by **[Cyrille MODIANO]** of my file & use it. The issue got resolved.

```
 iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t UTF-8 unittesting.txt -o unittesting_out.txt
```

My challenge now is that I don't know the character set of the incoming files & its coming from different different sources. The output of `file -i` i get for my source data file is :

```
: inode/x-empty; charset=binary
```

From my understanding, charset=binary means that the character set is unknown. Please advise what I can do in this case. Any small advice/ idea is much appreciated.

Comment: you should convert your input file to utf8, it encoded in iso-8859-1

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO Thanks, let me edit my question.

Comment: What happens if you don't set your characterset at all in the controlfile and let oracle do the conversion for you. I think the issue is you tell oracle the file is UTF8 and it isn't.

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO I tried this before, it doesn't help. What I did now is requested the source to provide the character set they are using. This should make my job easy. Once i can finalize that the difference between the character set is a problem I should be able to enforce it throughout to provide files encoded in UTF8.